# Unimodular row condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n)$ be a unimodular row over a commutative ring with unity $A$.
>
> Then there exists $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i=1$.

Now given a unimodular row it is given that

**we get an exact sequence $0\rightarrow A\longrightarrow A^n\rightarrow P\rightarrow 0$ where $P$ is a projective module of rank $n-1$ over $A$ and $P\oplus A\cong A^n$**.

I am not able to understand the above bolded line at all.Will someone please tell me how is it done?

If not can  someone please tell me where can I find material on the above.

Answer (score 1):

We more naturally get an exact sequence $0\to P\to A^n\to A\to0$, but as it splits we get an exact sequence the other way too. The map $\pi:A^n\to A$ is given by
$$(r_1,\ldots,r_n)\mapsto\sum_i r_i a_i.$$
Unimodularity means $\pi$ is surjective, so we get a
short exact sequence $0\to P\to A^n\to A\to0$.
As $A$ is projective, this splits, so $P$ is a direct summand
of the projective module $A^n$ and so is projective. To get the rank,
localise at a prime ideal, and the localised sequence now consists
of free modules, so the localisation of $P$ has rank $n-1$.

Comment: Sorry,I am not getting how do we get $P$ naturally as you said;Is it possible to give some more details

Comment: @Learnmore $P$ is just the kernel of $\pi$.